# OpenMP compiles with different flags gives different results

Tags: openmp, fortran90

I developed a FORTRAN code which I compiled with the following command:

```
ifort -g -O0 -openmp -openmp_report -threads -ipo
```

When running this code with the above flags, I keep the result with 15 digits when running serial and parallel (OpenMP). I have also checked with Intel Inspector 2013 - and I do not have any data race condition.

However, when I change the optimization compilation flag to `-O2` or `-O3`, I get a small error which grows with time (it is a simulation which integrates over time) from the order of `10^15` towards larger numbers.
The results with either one of `-O2` or `-O3` are different (up to the fifth digits after the dot).

Can anyone advise on how can I, in general, improve my code in order it to run with the same precision (double precision) as with `-O0` flag ?

Thanks in advance,
Jack.

Comment: Do you get an error that grows bigger, or do you get different results that differ more and more? If a small difference in the way your calculation runs changes the results, then what makes you think the first result is "correct" and the second has an error?

Comment: The error is definitely 'crawling' from small numbers to larger numbers. I refer the serial code with no optimization to be the correct answer, since I worked with it previously.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the numerical stability of your algorithm. You may want to consider some modifications there.

Comment: Thanks IanH.
I do not think that this is the issue.
There is no reason to think that different compiler (IFORT 2013) optimization will lead to stability / instability if the scheme is stable with -O0. 
Can you elaborate on how a numerical scheme (~thus stability) can be affected by optimization ?
Thanks again !

Comment: Well, my reasoning is that you appear to have very small errors propagating through your system that grow larger and larger. It is really just a guess though. I did just find a similar discussion [here](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1516). Their case wasn't exactly the same, but it was similar. It looks like the problem there was due to truncation of extended precision numbers, but I don't see how they resolved it. Perhaps if there is a way to make the algorithm more resistant to the propagation of floating point error, that could help.

Comment: Here's another [helpful discussion](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/361052).

Comment: Guys thanks very much for you comments.
What worked for me is optimize (-03) with (-fp-model strict) which keeps the same floating point model with the 'fast' optimization.